# How to auto generate parent MMD columns based on child MMD columns?

Tags: lookup-column, managed-metadata, client-object-model

This is the structure of one of my Term Sets. [image]

I have a Site Column called Record Type (Deeds, Agreements, Permits)
I have a Site Column called Deed Type (D1, D2, D3)
I have a Site Column called Permit Type (P1, P2, P3)
I have a Site Column called Agreement Type (A1, A2, A3)

Suppose a user is uploading or creating a new document, when he/she is entering the metadata, he/she enters "D2" for the Deed Type, is there a way to auto populate the record type column with "Deeds"?

I realize that this question might be too generic, but if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thank you